# How to convert sql query to linq query

Tags: linq

how to convert this sql query to linq query? in asp.net

```
 SELECT  distinct  P.Pid,P.Name,PC.categoryName, 
(select count(id) from POrderdetails where id=p.Pid)as detailsCount
FROM PTable P INNER JOIN PCATEGORY PC ON PC.pcategoryId=P.pCategoryId
ORDER BY detailsCount desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, I've updated this to include the category name.  Note that the query selects them into an anonymous object -- you can change that if you have an actual class with the properties by using the class constructor with property assignment instead.  Note that I also gave the count a different name. As you already have a Pid, I thought pid, would be too confusing.

```
 var products = PTable.Select( p => new {
                                 Pid = p.Pid,
                                 Name = p.Name,
                                 DetailCount = p.Orderdetails.Count(),
                                 Category = p.PCATEGORY.CategoryName
                        });
```