# Converting SQL query to Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I want to convert this query to LINQ / EF

```
select a.ArticleId, COUNT(*) as total from Articles a
inner join MetaKeywords b on a.ArticleId = b.ArticleId 
where b.MetaKeyword in ('_catalog', '_register')
group by a.ArticleId
having COUNT(*) >= 2
```

I tried many options but result was not as desired.

In the above query 2 is number of keywords to searched from child table..

Comment: "I tried many options but result was not as desired." => please post what you've tried.

Comment: Do you want to have this exact query translated to LINQ, or do you want a query that will "find all ArticleIDs that have some MetaKeyword  duplicated" (like, more than one _register or more than one _catalog or more than one ...)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530925/linq-using-inner-join-group-and-sum

Comment: Try LINQPAd or LINQUER

Comment: Try using Codereview for questions like this.

Comment: btw, "where" expression can be added into "on"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert sql query to linq query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531241/how-to-convert-sql-query-to-linq-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
var lst= new string[]{"_catalog","_register"};

var qry = (from a in db.Articles 
          join b MetaKeywords on a.ArticleId equals b.ArticleId
          where lst.Contains(b.MetaKeyword)
          group a by a.ArticleId into g
          where g.Count() >= 2
          select new {ArticleId = g.Key, Total = g.Count()} );
```

You should note that the `lst` is declared *outside* the actual query.

Answer (score 1):

Using method chaining:

```
var list=new[]{"_catalog","_register"};
var result=Articles
    .Join(MetaKeyWords,t=>t.ArticleId,t=>t.ArticleId,(article,metakeywords)=>new{article,metakeywords})
    .Where(t=>list.Contains(t.metakeywords.MetaKeyword))
    .GroupBy(t=>t.article.ArticleId)
    .Select(t=>new{ ArticleId=t.Key,Total=t.Count()})
    .Where(t=>t.Total>=2);
```

Comment: Much better (+1) but *I* think it is still pretty hard to read... syntax-wise. the `Join` always gets me lost :)